# Implementing custom learning rate scheduler in Pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I would like to implement this learning rate method as in the paper Attention is all you need. I have this code in Tensorflow, but I would like to implement it in Pytorch too. I know that Pytorch has modules for this (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html), but how could I go about making a custom scheduler? Or perhaps one of the above lr_scheduler already fulfils the same function?

Tensorflow code:

```
class CustomSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
  def __init__(self, d_model, warmup_steps=4000):
    super(CustomSchedule, self).__init__()

    self.d_model = d_model
    self.d_model = tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32)

    self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps

  def __call__(self, step):
    arg1 = tf.math.rsqrt(step)
    arg2 = step * (self.warmup_steps ** -1.5)

    return tf.math.rsqrt(self.d_model) * tf.math.minimum(arg1, arg2)

learning_rate = CustomSchedule(d_model)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98,
                                     epsilon=1e-9)
```

Pytorch?

```
import torch 

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)

scheduler =
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a scheduler used in a popular paper ([Attention is all you need](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf)), reasonably good implementations already exist online.

You can grab a PyTorch implementation from [this repository](https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch/blob/132907dd272e2cc92e3c10e6c4e783a87ff8893d/transformer/Optim.py#L4) by [@jadore801120](https://github.com/jadore801120).

Once you have it, then simply

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)
sched = ScheduledOptim(optimizer, d_model=..., n_warmup_steps=...)
```

also make sure to invoke the scheduler at the right time

```
for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
    sched.zero_grad()
    ...
    loss.backward()
    sched.step_and_update_lr()
```

Comment: ok thanks, i found that repo too